# How can I select all elements of a certain class, that are not immediate siblings of an element of the same class?

Tags: html, css

For instance, I want to select the middle element of the following

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

but none of the following elements

```
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

and of course not any of the following either

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Given the CSS level 3 selectors (https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors), the last element or psuedo-element targeted by the selector is the one that styles are applied to. Because of this, you cannot look ahead to younger siblings in the DOM and base your decision off of it.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, given that you want to exclude an element based on its subsequent sibling (as well as an element based on its previous sibling, which CSS *can* do). This may be a case where JavaScript is necessary.

Comment: Should be pretty easy if you wanted to use jQuery though

Comment: Incidentally, jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/001v3vn4/ and plain JS (ES2015): https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/001v3vn4/1/ or 'older' JS: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/001v3vn4/2/.